# now() as a default value in postgres

Tags: php, postgresql, activerecord, default-value

I'm using PHP & PotgreSQL to make an interface for a DB,
using this Active Record implementation for PHP -> http://www.phpactiverecord.org

It's quite useful, but there is a small trouble:
when you define a timestamp field in a table with "now()" as default value - this
engine does not get it :-(

SQL used to query information about columns is here:

```
SELECT 
  a.attname AS field, 
  a.attlen,
 REPLACE
 (
   pg_catalog.format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod), 
   'character varying', 
   'varchar'
 ) AS type,
 a.attnotnull AS not_nullable, 
 i.indisprimary as pk,
 REGEXP_REPLACE
 (
   REGEXP_REPLACE
   (
     REGEXP_REPLACE(s.column_default,'::[a-z_ ]+',''),
     '\'$',''
   ),
   '^\'',''
 ) AS default
 FROM 
   pg_catalog.pg_attribute a
 LEFT JOIN 
   pg_catalog.pg_class c ON(a.attrelid=c.oid)
 LEFT JOIN 
   pg_catalog.pg_index i ON(c.oid=i.indrelid AND a.attnum=any(i.indkey))
 LEFT JOIN 
   information_schema.columns s 
   ON(s.table_name=???? AND a.attname=s.column_name)
 WHERE 
   a.attrelid = (select c.oid from pg_catalog.pg_class c inner join 
   pg_catalog.pg_namespace n on(n.oid=c.relnamespace) where c.relname=?????
   and pg_catalog.pg_table_is_visible(c.oid))
   AND a.attnum > 0
   AND NOT a.attisdropped
 ORDER BY a.attnum`
```

????? is changed to the table name.

for timestamp column this code returns '' or null (I'm not sure which one) as a default value. How can I modify it to return 'now()' or even better - result of now()?

(same for any other column with function result as a default value)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Run `psql` with the -E option and do a `\d my_table` to display the table's definition.

psql will show you the SQL that it uses internally. 
That should give you everything you need.

Comment: Accept his answer as answer if it was your answer